# Choosing A PartitionKey in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, partitioning

I have a bunch of documents. Right now only about 100,000. But I could potentially have millions. These documents are each about 15KB each.

Right now the way I'm calculating the partition key is to take the Id field from Sql, which is set to autoincrement by 1, and dividing that number by 1000. I think this is not a good idea.

Sometimes I have to hit the CosmosDB very hard with parallel writes. When I do this, the documents usually have very closely grouped SQL Ids. For example, like this:

```
12000
12004
12009
12045
12080
12090
12102
```

As you can see, all of these documents would be written at the same time to the same partition because they would all have a partition key of 12. And from the documentation I've read, this is not good. I should be spreading my writes across partitions.

I'm considering changing this so that the PartitionKey is the Sql Id divided by 10,000 plus the last digit. Assuming that the group of Ids being written at the same time are randomly distributed (which they pretty much are).

So like this:

```
(12045 / 10000).ToString() + (12045 % 10).ToString()
```

This means, given my list above, the partition keys would be:

```
12000: 10
12004: 14
12009: 19
12045: 15
12080: 10
12090: 10
12102: 12
```

Instead of writing all 7 to a single partition, this will write all 7 to partitions 10, 12, 14, 15, and 19 (5 total). Will this result in faster write times? What are the effects on read time? Am I doing this right?

Also, is it better to have the first part of the key be the Id / 1000 or Id / 1000000? In other words, is it better to have lots of small partitions or should I aim to fill up the 10 GB limit of single partitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should aim at evenly distributing load between your partitions. 10gb is the limit,you shouldn't aim to hit that limit (because that would mean you wont be able to add documents to the partition anymore).

Creating a synthetic partition key is a valid way to distribute your documents evenly between partitions. Its up to you to find\invent a key that would fit your load pattern.

Comment: I hope this doesn't sound stupid, but should I just use the Sql Id as the partition key? One document per partition? What are the downsides to that? It seems at face value a bad idea but if it is, I cannot articulate why.

Comment: 1 documents per partition is probably not the best idea (but from what I know partition key count is unlimited). its especially bad if you need to query documents in different partitions (more expensive\slower)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply take the last digit of your Id, thus nicely spreading the documents over exactly 10 partitions.

In regards to your comment on max partitions: the value of the partitionKey is hashed and THAT hash determines the physical partitions. So when your partitionKey has 1.000 possible values, it does not mean you have 1.000 partitions.